# webpack Illegal instruction

Tags: webpack

My environment:

- win7-64
- node -v : v4.4.7
- npm -v : v3.10.3

After I installed webpack, running `webpack -v`, gives this error

```
/c/Users/Administrator/.npm-global/webpack: line 14:  9612 Illegal instruction  node "$basedir/node_modules/.webpack_npminstall/webpa                                                                                                                            ck/1.13.1/webpack/bin/webpack.js" "$@"
```

[image]

I tried to run `npm uninstall -g webpack` and to delete the `node_modules\.webpack_npminstall`  folder , then installing it again `npm i -g webpack`, it still failed. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I tried to update my os to win10,then webpack & webpack-dev-server works,so wired :(

Comment: Work on a remote linux machine